# JAVA TLS SOCKETS: bufferedreader.ready() always false

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, iostream, readline

I want to programm al small "chat" Programm using TLS

I am having trouble with SSL Sockets an Input streams. The TLS part works fine.

My Problem is : "`bufferedreader.ready()`"  always returns `false`. 
if i delete teh if -satetmant if works "fine". The programm waits until there is an \n or \r and prints is to System.out. But I can not send messages in that time.

"client"

```
  InputStream inputstream = System.in;
  InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
  BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

        InputStream inputstream1 = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader1 = new InputStreamReader(inputstream1);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader1 = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader1);

        OutputStream outputstream = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
        BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);

        OutputStream outputstream1 = System.out;
        OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter1 = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream1);
        BufferedWriter bufferedwriter1 = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter1);
        //Mitteilen, welchen Kommprofil zum verbindugn genutzt werden soll.
        bufferedwriter.write("bez\n");

        while (true) {

            if (bufferedreader.ready()) {
                bufferedwriter.write(bufferedreader.readLine() + '\n');
                bufferedwriter.flush();
            }
            if (bufferedreader1.ready()) {
                bufferedwriter1.write(bufferedreader1.readLine() + '\n');
                bufferedwriter1.flush();
            }


        }
```

"Server":

```
 InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

        InputStream inputstream1 = System.in;
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader1 = new InputStreamReader(inputstream1);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader1 = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader1);

        OutputStream outputstream = System.out;
        OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
        BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);

        OutputStream outputstream1 = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter1 = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream1);
        BufferedWriter bufferedwriter1 = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter1);



        while (true ) {
            if (bufferedreader.ready()) {
                bufferedwriter.write(bufferedreader.readLine() + '\n');
                bufferedwriter.flush();

            }
            if (bufferedreader1.ready()) {
                bufferedwriter1.write(bufferedreader1.readLine() + '\n');
                bufferedwriter1.flush();

            }

        }
```

Comment: What is your purpose of checking the result of the ready method?

Comment: Instead of BufferedWriter use PrintWriter. new PrintWriter("out put stream", true);

Comment: I want to check the ready method, so taht i know if there are information in the stream i need to print.

Comment: PrintWriter did not help teh situation.

Answer (score 0):

As you have nothing else to do in your loop *except* call readLine(), just call it. It will block until something arrives. You don't need to call ready() at all in thus situation, or indeed in its any situation.

Comment: Yes, but i want to read 2 different streams. So i dont want to block whiel readying one stream

Comment: Well as `ready()` doesn't work over `SSLSockets`, you don't have any choice about this. Use two threads.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" my Problem with this workaround:

```
public class CopyStreamThread extends Thread {

    private BufferedWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public CopyStreamThread(BufferedWriter out, BufferedReader in) {
        this.out = out;
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                out.write(in.readLine() + '\n');
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CopyStreamThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

"clinet/Server"

```
new CopyStreamThread(bufferedwriter, bufferedreader).start();
        new CopyStreamThread(bufferedwriter1, bufferedreader1).start();
```

i divided the waitung for input in 2 threads which isnt a nice soulution but it works.

Thanks for support.

Comment: Incorrect. This code will run forever, or until the Sun goes nova. You must check the result of `readLine()` for null, and stop the loop and close the input if you get it.